# Set keyboard focus to a window

Tags: c#, wpf, keyboard, focus

I would like to set the keyboard focus into a pop-up window but the Keyboard.FocusedElement; return always the same element event when I try to focus on the window.

I did try:

```
    var focusedControl1 = Keyboard.FocusedElement;
    FocusManager.SetIsFocusScope(this, true);
    FocusManager.SetFocusedElement(this, this);
    var focusedControl2 = Keyboard.FocusedElement;
```

and

```
    var focusedControl1 = Keyboard.FocusedElement;
    this.Focus();
    var focusedControl2 = Keyboard.FocusedElement;
```

and

```
    var focusedControl1 = Keyboard.FocusedElement;
    Keyboard.Focus(this);
    var focusedControl2 = Keyboard.FocusedElement;
```

But focusedControl1 and focusedControl2 are always the same. It is always an element from the MainWindow, not from the pop-up window. What is the secret to set a focus to a pop-up window ?
Thank you

Comment: for a popup are can use window.ShowDialog() method but that will open popup as child control of current window.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to focus on a window try below:

```
window.Activate();
```